# Hall-of-mirrors effect when using UIView animations on the TV Out screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiwebview

I'm doing an animation between two UIWebView's on the TV Out screen, and i get this effect both in the simulator and with a real device:

[image]

Basically, in my 2nd UIScreen, i've got a UIWindow, and inside that there is a UIView with a black background, and inside the uiview's i'm animating between two UIWebView's using the following code:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:oldWebView toView:newWebView
    duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

And i don't understand why, mid-animation, i get the hall-of-mirrors effect instead of seeing the black background of my UIView superview. Can someone please help?

Comment: Strangely enough, this problem disappears when using ios 5 - on 4.3 it's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i determined this was a ios <=4.3 bug, and simply disabled animations if we're using an os older than ios 5.